# Extract Strings from unstructured open-question [R]

Tags: r, string, text, substring

I'm trying to extract some strings from a variable which contains free text (so this variable is not structured at all). My goal is to extract the three answers they gave to the respective three questions asked. Even if the content is messy, the variable can however be broke down as follow :

NAME Surname, dd/mm/yyyy at hh:mm:ss Q1 Q2 Q3

Some respondents did use markers such as :

SMITH John at 10:01:36 **1°** I agree blabla **2°** My opinion about blabla **3°** No

MAC DONALD Ronald at 02:26:02 **1)** I disagree but blabla **2)** I'm 100% positive that blabla **3)** yes

CURIE Mary at 11:00:56 **-** I cannot say that blabla **-** Definitely yes **-** not applicable

So as you can see the markers - emphasized in bold - (and if used) happen to differ. And the answers are highly heterogeneous.

Therefore my question is, would it be possible to handle these text flaws and substract each answer and put it into respective variables ? And if not, would it be possible if the structure of each answer was the same (I mean with the same marker).

Thanks a lot in advance for your clues.

Comment: How impolite.. Hello everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below replace `textConnection(Lines)` with the name of your file if the data is coming from a file.  We replace the separators with semicolon but choose a different character if there are any semicolons in your input.

```
# input
Lines <- r"{
SMITH John at 10:01:36 1° I agree blabla 2° My opinion about blabla 3° No
MAC DONALD Ronald at 02:26:02 1) I disagree but blabla 2) I'm 100% positive that blabla 3) yes
CURIE Mary at 11:00:56 - I cannot say that blabla - Definitely yes - not applicable}"

L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))  # read it into separate lines

L2 <- gsub("\\d+°|\\d+\\)|-", ";", L)  # replace separators with semicolon

# if we included all separators then this should emit character(0)
num <- count.fields(textConnection(L2), sep = ";", quote = "")
L2[num != 4]
## character(0)

# if there were some separators that were not included in the gsub 
# we will see the offending lines above and can add their separators to gsub pattern
# above and then rerun everything from the gsub line onwards with modified pattern

# finally if we have included all the separators we can read it in
read.table(text = L2, sep = ";", strip.white = TRUE, quote = "")
```

giving:

```
                             V1                       V2                            V3             V4
1        SMITH John at 10:01:36           I agree blabla       My opinion about blabla             No
2 MAC DONALD Ronald at 02:26:02    I disagree but blabla I'm 100% positive that blabla            yes
3        CURIE Mary at 11:00:56 I cannot say that blabla                Definitely yes not applicable
```